emacs server on linux, client on windows - Please specify display
I want to run an emacs server on a ubuntu (headless) machine, and a client on a windows 11.
I have set up the server to use tcp, have shared the authentication key, and made ssh port forwarding, so connection is established. However, it doesn't work... I do:
c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\emacsclient.exe  -f path-to-server-file/server -c

Nothing happens on the client side, and on the server, I get the following in the *server* buffer:
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Status changed to open: open from 127.0.0.1
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: server-delete-client
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Received -auth (,x:Cnet=;N+%t=2FZco1o#3S*<)|SNunp*kP#1kXgtE.Ih.77USA^(?HdhEGU#y -env ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData -env ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk -env ANDROI\
D_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk -env APPDATA=C:\Users\simon\AppData\Roaming -env APR_ICONV_PATH=C:\Program&_Files&_(x86)\Subversion\iconv -env CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true -env ChocolateyInstall=C:\ProgramData\ch\
ocolatey -env ChocolateyLastPathUpdate=133287155695769196 -env ChocolateyToolsLocation=C:\tools -env COLUMNS=238 -env CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program&_Files\Common&_Files -env CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program&_Files&_(x86)\Common&_Files \
-env CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program&_Files\Common&_Files -env COMPUTERNAME=MATRIX -env ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe -env DISPLAY=:0 -env DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData -env editor=nano -env GIT_LFS_PATH=C:\Progra\
m&_Files\Git&_LFS -env GNUPLOT_LIB=C:\Program&_Files\gnuplot\demo;C:\Program&_Files\gnuplot\demo\games;C:\Program&_Files\gnuplot\share -env HOMEDRIVE=C: -env HOMEPATH=\Users\simon -env IGCCSVC_DB=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAACDz6zulq5\
0SvQv3djvjH8wQAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAA00VOUvH8txXraVzWX40EOU6XOeNQv+lN3Z/Nsn6pLGQAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAACH+Wep8inML0sY6HSf/HulDD5uepBe9UrOpLSxyoLBiWAAAAAVwQPn9ds66JrQSgdgmQc3cdX1XvsZFcCeOQq7mLwk2BUyFaUaRqh3b5h5zRU82BpVM6BrCjrENIUHQDDsj9\
5sF17UqtKw87bcs+rOcrgv30GX0CmhrVo4be113TLvrOVAAAAAXidKLMdLShyeyNZyouDlKjg/FuPa2vTn6/nTNYiyadorfQ887xXuPYSHKLjqD7AWSSeP2lAcSNjfgKx9LoPG9w== -env JAVA_HOME=C:\pf\Android\Android&_Studio\jbr -env LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local -e\
nv LOGONSERVER=\\MATRIX -env NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8 -env OneDrive=C:\Users\simon\OneDrive&_-&_Lincode&_AB -env OneDriveCommercial=C:\Users\simon\OneDrive&_-&_Lincode&_AB -env OS=Windows_NT -env Path=C:\Program&_Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Vulk\
anSDK\1.3.268.0\Bin;C:\Program&_Files\OpenSSH\;C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.243.0\Bin;C:\pf\Git\usr\bin;C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.204.1\Bin;C:\Users\simon\.cargo\bin;C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.2\Bin;C:\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python310\;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Pytho\
n39\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\pf\Git&_LFS;C:\pf\LLVM\bin;C:\pf\Microsoft&_VS&_Code\bin;C:\pf\dotnet\\
;C:\pf\gnuplot\bin;C:\pf\MATLAB\R2023a\runtime\win64;C:\pf\MATLAB\R2023a\bin;C:\pf\MATLAB\R2021b\bin;C:\pf\Git\cmd;C:\pf\CMake\bin;C:\pf\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShel\
l\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program&_Files&_(x86)\wol;C:\Program&_Files&_(x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program&_Files\LLVM\bin;C:\Program&_Files\dotnet\;C:\Program&_Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program&_Files\Microsoft&_SQL&_Server\150\Tools\
\Binn\;C:\Program&_Files\Microsoft&_SQL&_Server\Client&_SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program&_Files&_(x86)\Windows&_Kits\10\Windows&_Performance&_Toolkit\;C:\Program&_Files&_(x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program&_Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program&_Files\Dock\
er\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program&_Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program&_Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\simon\scoop\apps\gsudo\current;C:\Users\simon\scoop\shims;C:\pf\Git\usr\bin;C:\pf\PowerShell\7;C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.204.1\Bin;C:\Users\simon\.cargo\bi\
n;C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.2\Bin;C:\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python310\;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Progra\
mData\chocolatey\bin;C:\pf\Git&_LFS;C:\pf\LLVM\bin;C:\pf\Microsoft&_VS&_Code\bin;C:\Program&_Files&_(x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\pf\dotnet\;C:\pf\gnuplot\bin;C:\pf\MATLAB\R2023a\runtime\win64;C:\pf\MATLAB\R2023a\bin;C:\pf\MATLAB\R2021b\bin;C:\pf\G\
it\cmd;C:\pf\CMake\bin;C:\pf\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program&_Files&_(x86)\wol;C:\pf\PowerShell\7\;C:\Users\simon\AppData\
\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program&_Files\smartmontools\bin;c:\users\s
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Authentication successful
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Sent -emacs-pid 1397048
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Received imon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud&_SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\simon\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C\
:\Users\simon\AppData\Roaming\npm -env PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW;.CPL -env POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL=MSI:Windows&_10&_Pro -env PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64 -env PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Inte\
l64&_Family&_6&_Model&_140&_Stepping&_1,&_GenuineIntel -env PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6 -env PROCESSOR_REVISION=8c01 -env ProgramData=C:\ProgramData -env ProgramFiles=C:\Program&_Files -env ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program&_Files&_(x86) -env ProgramW6\
432=C:\Program&_Files -env PSModulePath=C:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Users\simon\Documents\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program&_Files\PowerShell\Modules;c:\program&_files\powershell\7\Modules;C:\Users\simon\scoop\mod\
ules;C:\Users\simon\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud&_SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\PowerShell;C:\Program&_Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules -e\
nv PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public -env SESSIONNAME=Console -env SystemDrive=C: -env SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS -env TEMP=C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Temp -env TMP=C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Temp -env USERDOMAIN=MATRIX -env USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFIL\
E=MATRIX -env USERNAME=simon -env USERPROFILE=C:\Users\simon -env VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program&_Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ -env VK_SDK_PATH=C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.268.0 -env VULKAN_SDK=C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.268.0 -env windir=C:\WINDOWS -env wo_wo\
rk=c:\users\simon\.wo -env WSLENV=WT_SESSION:WT_PROFILE_ID: -env WT_PROFILE_ID={574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336} -env WT_SESSION=5b7522da-0807-4df5-a313-5e8dabeb0878 -env ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN=1 -dir C:\Users\simon\src\Octoplus/ -tty CO\
NOUT$ w32console
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Sent -emacs-pid 1397048
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Sent -error Please&_specify&_display
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Please specify display
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Status changed to closed: connection broken by remote peer
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: server-delete-client
Sun Nov  3 15:18:32 2024 server <127.0.0.1:38586>: Deleted

I have tried adding -d w32 to the client commandline, makes no difference, also emacsclientw behaves the same. Am I trying to achieve something that is not supported?
emacs version is 29.4 on both sides

What do you expect should happen? Where should Emacs (running on headless Ubuntu) create the frame that you asked for?

Try having a look at emacs TRAMP. That is probably what you are looking for. Instead of clienting a remote machine you start a session on windows and login to the remote file system (your server).

@NickD: I expect the frame to be created on the client machine

TRAMP seems to do what I want, thanks @Tietan.

"I expect the frame to be created on the client machine": Emacs has no idea how to create a frame on a remote machine. It can be done (e.g. if you run an X11 server on your Windows machine and specify the display for your Emacs to point to the remote X11 server - X11 is doing all the work to create the remote frame in that case, not Emacs), but it's not something that you can get out of the box: you need to set it up. OTOH, if what you want is remote file access, then as @Tietan points out, tramp is sufficient.

@NickD, well I guess I expected the emacsclient to create the frame on the client side, but that is apparently not how the emacs folks interpreted the idea of clients and servers. Anyhow, I'm good with tramp.

emacsclient is a very simple program: it sends a command to Emacs and either disconnects immediately (with the -n option) or waits for Emacs to close the connection. That's all it does.

TRAMP is the solution ion my case, not client/server.
